# Auto Regressive (AR) model using Maximum Likelihood Estimator in pandas dataframe: correlate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'old behavior'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have a subset of a pandas dataframe that contains a time series I want to analyze with an AR or ARIMA model using statsmodel:

```
data_sci = H_Clinton_social_vector.Florida
```

The data looks like this:

```
Date
    2015-09-28     587
    2015-10-05     582
    2015-10-12     606
    2015-10-19     698
```

My AR model is created like this, aggregating the time series on a weekly basis:

```
ar_model = sm.tsa.AR(data_sci, freq='W')
ar_model
<statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR at 0x1178f5490>
```

Next, I want to do a Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) fit of the AR parameters, with a half year lag:

```
ar_res = ar_model.fit(maxlag=26, method='mle')
```

I get the following results:

```
correlate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'old behavior'
```

I don't understand what the problem is, which I assume is related to the auto correlation of the data, due the correlate() argument. There is high autocorrelation in my data so this should be ok.

[image: autocorrelation of dataset]

I am not very familiar with stasmodels, and prefer avoding coding an AR or ARIMA model from scratch.

Comment: What's your statsmodels version and what's the numpy version. One possibility is that this is an old statsmodels that uses options that have been removed from recent numpy.

Comment: Thank you. My statsmodel is 0.6.1. and numpy is 1.10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, the problem was **incompatibility of statsmodel with numpy 1.10**. Although I had the latest release of stasmodel, there was an internal problem with autocorrelation (incompatibility with latest version of numpy), that required the install of the master code at [Github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels).

First, I found out what versions of stasmodels' dependencies I had:

```
Python >= 2.6, including Python 3.x
NumPy >= 1.5.1
SciPy >= 0.9.0
Pandas >= 0.7.1
Patsy >= 0.3.0
```

All of them were OK, so in order to install from source, I needed to have **Cython >= 20.1**, which I downloaded from [here](http://cython.org/#download). Uncompress, navigate to that directory and do:

```
python setup.py install
```

After that is done, navigate to the downloaded copy of statsmodel from [Github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels), and build stasmodel:

```
python setup.py install
```

You'll see:

```
Cythonizing sources
Processing statsmodels/nonparametric/_smoothers_lowess.pyx
Processing statsmodels/nonparametric/linbin.pyx
Processing statsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.pyx
Processing statsmodels/tsa/statespace/_statespace.pyx.in
```

etc. After a while, you'll have the latest build of statsmodel. Now my AR model works fine, although with some warnings that you can ignore or disable.

Comment: It looks like there are additional bugs that were fixed in numpy 1.10.2 that affect the new statespace model that are in master. So, I would recommend to upgrade also numpy if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to downgrade `numpy` to version `1.9.2` or below, just tested and did not get this error for your code anymore. It is due to a call to `np.correlate()` in `_presample_varcov` where `statsmodels.tsa.armodel` calculates the inverse of the presample variance-covariance.

`Numpy` has deprecated the use of `multiarray.correlate()` (the `old behavior`) with `1.10` around June 2015 [(see docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), but `statsmodels` has not been updated in this respect (`0.6.1` dates from December 2014).

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, but downgrading to a lower numpy version would create more problems than the one I am trying to solve.

Comment: Alternatively, you could fork and update the relevant `statsmodel` code yourself - see `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.py` around line 260. Or use some other package, but I'm not aware of any other free time series implementation in `python`.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, I was able to solve the issue by rebuilding statsmodel from source from the latest one at Github (it is solved in the current one, not in 0.6.1)